# Why @sys.any captures text incorrectly?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm working with dialogflow for a project and I want to capture "fmr-name" and other parameters from an intent correctly.Please see the following pictures:

[image: first photo]

[image: second photo]

[image: third photo]

as you can see, when I enter "change 1 bedroom rent of sandy to $123", it doesn't capture "fmr-name" correctly,so all the parameters are being captured wrong and I get "Please enter a rent price as number and with currency." response that is "define prompt" part of "unit-currency" because of getting its value incorrectly.Does any body know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you've specified the phrase as

```
Change @PlaceName rent of @sys.any FMR to @sys.unit-currency
```

but when you're testing it, you're saying

> Change 1 bedroom rent of sandy to $1100

and omitting the "FMR" part. I don't know how the language processing works exactly, but I can see the `@sys.any` parameter being overly greedy if it doesn't find an exact match of words on each side of it.

Try adding another phrase that omits the "FMR" word and see if the matching works better.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and reply. It worked well with your exact guidance.